# How to open report in designer for old version of DevExpress (7.1)

Tags: devexpress

I work with the old project which uses an old version of DevExpress 7.1. As I found reports created for this version can't be open in any Visual Studio(at least not older than 2008).
So do you know any solution that I can use for creating and editing reports with visual designers? Or I can only work with it using code?
Thank you.

Comment: it may be solved by converting the project with DevExpress Project converter on Visual Studio. if the project can also be converted and your old version not a must.